# when i click on checkbox than input button will be clickable

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my form:

```
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
    <input type="button" name="update" value="Update Booking" id="Update_Booking" onClick="setUpdateAction();" />
    <input type="button" name="delete" value="Cancel Booking" onClick="setDeleteAction();" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="booking[]" id="Booking" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
</form>
```

This is script code:

```
function setUpdateAction() {
    document.frmUser.action = "update_booking_view.php";
    document.frmUser.submit();
}

function setDeleteAction() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete these rows?")) {
        document.frmUser.action = "delete_booking_view.php";
        document.frmUser.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use jQuery here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

**PS**: You need to prevent the default behaviour of the button click which submits the form.

**JS:**

```
function setUpdateAction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.frmUser.action = "update_booking_view.php";
    document.frmUser.submit();
}

function setDeleteAction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete these rows?")) {
        document.frmUser.action = "delete_booking_view.php";
        document.frmUser.submit();
    }
}

function toggleBtns(checkbox) {
    checkbox.form.update.disabled = checkbox.form.delete.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
    <input type="button" disabled name="update" value="Update Booking" id="Update_Booking" onClick="setUpdateAction(event);" />
    <input type="button" disabled name="delete" value="Cancel Booking" onClick="setDeleteAction(event);" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="booking[]" onchange="toggleBtns(this)" id="Booking" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
</form>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/jjhm2mnr/2/

Comment: thanx.. but i need more help. what should i do if i don't want checkbox by default checked

Answer (score 0):

You need to add disabled attribute to the two buttons initially.

Once you click on the checkbox, see if it's checked.
If checked, button becomes clickable.
If unchecked, button becomes disabled.

Modify your HTML by adding disabled attribute:

```
  <input type="button" name="update" value="Update Booking" id="Update_Booking" onClick="setUpdateAction();" disabled />
  <input type="button" name="delete" value="Cancel Booking" onClick="setDeleteAction();" disabled />
```

Then your jQuery:

```
    $("#Booking").on("click", function() {
       if (this.checked == true) {
          $("input[type='button']").attr('disabled', false);
       } else {
          $("input[type='button']").attr('disabled', true);
       }
    });
```

You can refer to this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ythw3sv6/

Comment: i try your code but some times buttons will clickable and some times not.